# Add space or margin to UIBarButtons in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Is possible to add a 5px margin to the buttons on my Navigation Bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a view to that navigation bar that has two subviews, one for the margin and one for the actual button. If that fails, try adding 5 (or for Retina displays 10) pixels to your image inside the button.

Comment: ok Ill accept your answer, but i didn't try the first option ,  i just used the second one..thanks